# Get values from json in different format

Tags: ios, json, swift

This is my API response...

```
{
    "organizations": [
        {
            "id": 12345,
            "name": “products1",
            "parentId": null,
            "plantId": 28768,
            "type": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 76532,
            "name": “products2",
            "parentId": 4270947,
            "plantId": null,
            "type": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Now since I have some issues with connectivity and so cannot call the API, get the response and parse, I have hard-coded the above response in my code like so..

```
var jsonObject = [String : [[String : Any?]]]()


jsonObject = [
    "organizations":[

    ["id": 12345, “name”: “products1”, “parentId”:”null”,"plantID”:28768,”type”:1],
    ["id": 76532, “name”: “products1”, “parentId”:”null”,"plantID”:28768,”type”:1]

    ]

]
```

And I parse this data and insert it into database like so...

```swift
let organizationLists = Organization()

guard let jsonArray = jsonObject as? [String : [[String : Any?]]] else { return }

for (_,value) in jsonArray {

    for object in value {

        organizationLists.id = object["id"] as? Int
        organizationLists.Name = object["name"] as? String
        organizationLists.parentID = object["parentID"] as? Int
        organizationLists.plantID = object["plantID"] as? Int
        organizationLists.loggedInUserId = object["type"] as? Int
        let isInserted = sharedInstance.saveOrganization_Lists(organizationLists)
    }            
}
```

Now with the above code, I'm able to properly insert the data also into the database. But I feel that there might be a better way to directly parse based on the `value` rather than using a `for loop` inside a `for loop` like above..or maybe a totally different and better method altogether...

**EDIT 1:** Class for Codable

```
class OrganizationLists: Codable{
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?
    var parentID: Int?
    var plantID: Int?
    var type: Int?

    //Initialize as usual
    init(id: Int, name: String, parentID: Int, plantID: Int, type: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.parentID = parentID
        self.plantID = plantID
        self.type = type
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes my dude. I'm about to change your life forever. Allow me to share a code snippet of great gloriousness that will make your life infinitely easier. #codable/decodable

Comment: Where does `jsonObject` come from? It's obviously already deserialized.

Comment: @xTwisteDx I'm sorry your *answer won't solve that* even if `jsonObject` was `Data`.

Comment: @vadian can you explain? I'm always up to learning something.

Comment: @vadian would you maybe mind suggesting an answer...

Comment: I'm getting much confused...:(...I cannot call an API since there is a connectivity issue..hence I hardcoded the response like shown in the question..

Comment: It seems I'll have to go with the method I have used already though it's not recommended...:(

Comment: You should use Codable for decoding but that is only half the solution isn't it? Your question is kind of vague but if you have an array of decoded objects then you can use  `map` on the array for instance to create an array of your current class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you receive the data from an *API response* as raw `Data` representing a JSON string.

```
let jsonString = """
{
    "organizations": [
        {
            "id": 12345,
            "name": "products1",
            "parentId": null,
            "plantId": 28768,
            "type": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 76532,
            "name": "products2",
            "parentId": 4270947,
            "plantId": null,
            "type": 2
        }
    ]
}
"""

let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
```

Don't use a `class` unless you really need a class and declare only those properties as optional which can be `nil`. If you are not going to modify the values declare the properties even as constants (`let`).

Further you need an umbrella struct for the root object

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let organizations : [Organization]
}

struct Organization : Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let parentID: Int?
    let plantID: Int?
    let type: Int
}
```

Now decode the data

```
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Just a note, if you use a Struct, you cannot pass objects by reference. If you know you'll be passing by ref, you'll need a Class, otherwise a Struct will suffice. I'd nearly call this sniping, but whatever. I'll be a good sport.

Comment: Please note *unless you really need a class*.

Comment: Pardon for the late reply @vadian. Thanks a lot for the answer.  Now I get this in the result :  `Root(organizations: [eSMAT.Organization1(id: 12345, name: “products1”, parentID: nil, plantID: Optional(28768),type: 1)…..])`.    But I'm confused as to how I can parse and get each of the individual elements from this response....

Comment: It's unclear what type your database accepts. If `Organization` is compatible then you can insert the array `result.organizations` directly. Otherwise make the database type conform to `Codable`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @vadian. I tried `result.organizations` and it is working fine. Just one more doubt..In case my json response did not have `organizations`, but instead was a simple one like `[
    {
        "id": 12345,
        "name": “products1”
 …
    }
]`  then how I could have used `Codable/Decodable`..?

Comment: Then decode `[Organization].self` instead of `Root.self`. Please learn to understand the pattern. Actually it's pretty easy.